# Dynamically Change Dates for an In Between Event

Tags: php

Based on a piece of coding from [Rounin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3897775/rounin) - I have taken this to try and come up with a method of, basically if todays date is between say 2017-03-01 and 2017-04-30, then display rego form.  If outside of these dates, then display "Form Not available"

The date in between is two set dates is easy to understand, but what I want to do is dynamically change the Y so I don't have to edit manually every year.

What I have is (although seems very unwieldy - but works?)

```
<?php

        $today = date('Y-m-d');


        $Current_Year = date('y');
        $Current_Month = date('n');
        $Current_Day = date('j');
        $Next_Year = ($Current_Year + 1);

        if ($Current_Month < 5) {
        $Begin_Rego_Year = $Current_Year;
        }

        if ($Current_Month > 3) {
        $Begin_Rego_Year = $Next_Year;
        }

        # Checks if date is March 31st
        if (($Current_Month == 3) && ($Current_Day == 1)) {
        $Begin_Rego_Year = $Current_Year;
        }

        $Begin_Rego_Date = $Begin_Rego_Year.'-03-01';


        /////////////////

        if ($Current_Month < 5) {
        $End_Rego_Year = $Current_Year;
        }

        if ($Current_Month > 3) {
        $End_Rego_Year = $Next_Year;
        }

        # Checks if date is March 31st
        if (($Current_Month == 4) && ($Current_Day == 30)) {
        $End_Rego_Year = $Current_Year;
        }

        $End_Rego_Date = $End_Rego_Year.'-04-30';

        if (($today >= $Begin_Rego_Date) && ($today <= $End_Rego_Date))
{
   echo "Display Rego Form"; //if todays date was between 01 Mar - 30 Apr 17
}

else {

   echo "Rego Form Offline until 01 Mar 18";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easist way to work with dates i think it is a function `strtotime`
<kbd>@usage example **`strtotime();`**</kbd>

```
if (
   strtotime('today')  >= strtotime('first day of this month') 
   && strtotime('today') <= strtotime('last day of this month')
) { 
    echo 'display rego form'; 
}
```

php.net
[Info about this function](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php)
[Info about date formats for strtotime](http://php.net/manual/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: Started working on this, just need to work out the dynamic Y bit

Comment: date formats helps of dynamic, such as 'last day of next month' or '10 Semptember 2016' or 'last day of April 2016'' and etc.. isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is legal.. strtotime('last day of april') - couldn't make it work.

Ended up with (so far)

```
$open_day = date('01-03-Y');
$close_day = date('30-04-Y');

if (
   strtotime('today')  >= strtotime($open_day) && strtotime('today') <= strtotime($close_day)
) { 
    echo 'display rego form'; 
}
else {
    echo 'Come back another time';
}
```